# RoundedRectangleBorder is not working for Container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to make Container edge circle and how to do that when i try RoundedRectangleBorder it showing error

```
 Container(
      width: 100,height: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.orange,
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
         )
      ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 6):

This error suggests,

> argument type `RoundedRectangleBorder` cannot be assigned to parameter type `BoxShape`

So if you want to use `RoundedRectangleBorder` then you have to use it inside `shape` parameter,

```
Container(
            width: 100,height: 100,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    decoration:  ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( // <--- use this
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
       ),
```

Output,

[image]

@Anil Chauhan's approach is also correct so you can use that too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 Container(
     width: 100,height: 100,
     margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.orange,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The container is no longer accepting RoundedRectangledBorder as a shape, You've to use the BoxShape class only for the shape property

But still, you can achieve the desired behavior like this

`Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width:2),color:Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.2),shape:BoxShape.rectangle,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),`

By doing this you can give borderRadius,shape and borders as well

if you're not getting the borderRadius the you can wrap your container inside a ClipRRect() and access the borderRadius property inside the ClipRRect